# Call to a non-object workaround?

Tags: php, class, methods, prepare

I have a method like this:

```
public function query ($sql) {
  $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Binds the query statement to the result variable. This is really handy because I have several methods that output something and another method that then handles the `$result` variable for other tasks.

However I wanted to use the same kind of method, but on prepared statements(to escape data that gets inserted) and I ran into a problem:

```
public function prepare ($sql) {
  $this->result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
}
```

I tried to use it like this:

```
public function insert ($this, $that) {
  // Then I tried to use my prepare method
  $var = $this->prepare(INSERT INTO Table (Row1, Row2) VALUES (:Val1, :Val2));
  $var->bindValue(":Val1", $this, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  //... and so on
}
```

The problem shows up on the `$var->bindValue()` "Call to a member function bindvalue() on a non-object". What is exactly happening here because I don't really understand the error message? If I query my db using the query method it works just fine, but how can I bind values using the prepare method?

Comment: I might assume you are overriding $this...change to another variable name...even for convention

Comment: Is this method `public function ($sql)` anonymous?

Comment: I assume you DO have "" aroud your query, and just missed them while typing the code on SO?

Comment: @Voitcus
No, just forgot to add names

Comment: `public function insert ($this, $that)` that's a horrible example. I'd suggest `$foo, $bar` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
public function ($sql) {
  $this->result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
}
```

You forget to return the result. (You also forgot the name of the function in the snippet.)

The error message is quite clear, you're calling a method on something that's not an object. In this case you're calling it on `NULL` because your own prepare-method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hah! You were right! As I understand I needed to return what the prepare() method produced or I was trying to bind values to pretty much nothing? and that resulted the error?

Comment: More specifically: you were trying to call a method on pretty much nothing.

Answer (score 0):

first off i noticed your methods don't have a name.

`public function ($sql) {
  $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
}`

shouldn't it be something like

`public function doSomething($sql) {
  $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
}`

secondly, it seems you are calling an instance of another class in your method.

`$this->db->query($sql)`
if am not wrong the 'db' should be anothe class that you are trying to access its query method...Look at your code again.

Lastly i you are missing a return statement.